# How to compute a prediction interval on rescaled power transformed data?

Tags: data-transformation, bootstrap, prediction-interval

Given a training dataset $\mathcal{D} = \{ (x_i, y_i) \in \mathbb{R}_+^2 | 1 \leq i \leq n\}$
one can fit a linear regression $y_i = a \cdot x_i + b + \varepsilon_i = \hat{y}_i + \varepsilon_i$.

That is, one can also compute a $2\alpha$-prediction interval assuming that the residuals are normally distributed :

$$ \hat{y}_0 \pm t_{\alpha, n-2} \sqrt{ \left [1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_0 - \bar{x})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2} \right] \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{[y_i - \hat{y}_i]^2}{n-2}} $$

One can find the proof of this formula under the normally distributed residuals assumption, with unknown mean and unknown variance.

If the data is heteroscedasticity, one would try to transform the data using a boxcox transformation or yoe-johnson one.

The model becomes then :
$$ \frac{y_i^\lambda - 1}{\lambda} = a \cdot \frac{x_i^\mu - 1}{\mu} + b +\varepsilon_i $$

But, if one want to compute the prediction interval based on this model, and want to rescale it on the original scale using the boxcox inverse function, one will face an issue. The prediction interval is computed from the residuals $\varepsilon_i$ and rescale them doesn't mean to have them on original scale.

So the question is how to compute the prediction interval in this case ? I would try to first rescale the predictions and then compute the prediction interval from the residuals using bootstraping (as they might not be gaussian in the original scale).

Is it a correct way to achieve this ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Could this be due to [Heteroscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity)? If so, there are ways to address this in linear regression...

Comment: Because the Box-Cox transformation is one-to-one, any prediction interval can readily be mathematically inverted to yield a prediction interval in the original scale.

Comment: Nice so I can compute the prediction interval in the transformed space and then inverse the transformation to find the prediction interval in the original space. I wrote a script to achieve this and the prediction interval is no longer symetric (as one would expected) and takes the heteroscedasticity into account. @whuber do you have some references I can check out. I am looking forward to have more details.

Comment: Could you indicate specifically what support you are looking for from these references?

Comment: Some books or articles dealing with heteroskedasticity, power transform, power transform and prediction interval, gaussian assumptions. If you cannot recommend me some papers it's ok :) Thank you again.

Comment: Any modern textbook on multiple regression will cover all these.